# Binding dynamically to ng-model for multi level deep object using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular JS and I have run into a problem. I am creating a dynamic form where the elements come from the Database for example:
order object:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string LenderName { get; set; }   
public PropertyModel Property { get; set; }
```

PropertyModel Object:

```
public string Zip{ get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
```

I was successfully able to dynamically bind ng-model for single level deep property like Example for Order.LenderName my input element is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="order[element.ModelName]"></input>
```

this perfectly binds to the $scope.order.LenderName

Note: element.ModelName = "LenderName" or rather I could say the order property name

my sample code is below:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in eventSchemaElementList">
    <div ng-switch="element.FieldTypeCode">
        <div class="topBottomPadding">
            <div class="col-sm-2 alignRight">
                <label>{{element.SchemaFieldName}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="TextBox" class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" ng-model="order[element.ModelName]" />
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="TextArea" class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea ng-model="order[element.ModelName]"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code I am not able to figure out How I can dynamically bind Order.Property.State to ng-model.
  the above code works only for one level deep. I am not sure how to do it for order.Property.State
  I also tried doing this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="order[element.ModelName]" />
```

Where element.ModelName = Property[State]

I also tried hardcoding it as order[Property[State]] in the input still did not work

```
<input type="text" ng-model="order[Property[State]]" />
```

For the above ones It does not bind to the order.Property.State but it creates a new property as Property[State]. It is really confusing because I have objects that go 4 or 5 level deep.

Help or suggestions will be really appreciated thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# so I'm not exactly sure what your model (data) looks like. Could you give us some example data in JSON so that we can run against your view?

I don't know if it's actually not allowed is JavaScript, but I don't write `order[Property[State]]` but use dot-notation `order.Property.State`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It actually works with order.Property.State but it should be hardcoded thats the issue and I am trying to bind to ng-model dynamically.

Comment: below is the example data in JSON Documents: Array[0]
Id: 0
LenderLoanNumber: "123124234"
LenderName: "ClientABC"
Product: "Something"
Property: Object
PropertyType: null
State: null

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you mean. You say it "should be hardcoded" but you want to "bind dynamically" that's kind of an oxymoron. Also, if you have the time, a JSFiddle would be great.

Comment: I mean when I use it like <input type="text" ng-model="order.Property.State" /> it works but I want to bind it dynamically using the object without having to say order.Property.State. I could provide a sample JSFiddle that would be better I guess .thanks alot for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the string order['Property']['State'] in controller e.g. $scope.myString = 'order[\'Property\'][\'State\']' and refer the same in ng-model as ng-model="a = myString".

Answer (score -1):

if u want to have order.Property.State

in json or array should be

name = property
and subname = state

which u can call order[element.name][element.subname]